# JavaScript - Reduce array and groupBy

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this simple array:

```json
[{
    color: "red",
    swatches: 6
}, {
    color: "green",
    swatches: 10
}, {
    color: "green",
    swatches: 10
}, {
    color: "red",
    swatches: 9
}, {
    color: "green",
    swatches: 10
}, {
    color: "blue",
    swatches: 5
}]
```

How would I use `.reduce()` and `.filter()` to add the count of `swatches` and group by `color`, so you'd get something like this:

```json
[{
    color: "red",
    swatches: 15
}, {
    color: "green",
    swatches: 30
}, {
    color: "blue",
    swatches: 5
}]
```

You might get away with using a `forEach` on it and then check if it's added in there but perhaps using an ES6 way is better? No lodash, please.

Comment: there is one thing wrong ... you haven't attempted to solve your own problem at all

Comment: @JaromandaX I've been playing with JSBin for a bit and I have a solution but it's pretty terrible so I am asking onlinee.

Comment: the point is to show your attempt in the question - otherwise the question looks like a request for code :p

Comment: @test even if what you have is terrible it's better than nothing. People tend to react negatively on SO when you just paste your requirements in the question. Makes you seem like you didn't try anything and you're just using SO as a code writing service. In your situation that wasn't the case, but how would anyone know?

Comment: Stack Overflow is about finding help for problems with code that you've actually written. This question is explicitly requesting code *to be written for you*.

Comment: @Jayce444  I understand that - I thought by telling you what functions I used, that'd be enough and now it seems it's been closed or deleted? Oh well, now I remember when I rarely posted here anymore. _shrug_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using nothing but ES6 functions, looks neat but not as fast as forEach I suppose.

```js
const data = [{
   color: "red",
   swatches: 6
}, {
   color: "green",
   swatches: 10
}, {
   color: "green",
   swatches: 10
}, {
   color: "red",
   swatches: 9
}, {
   color: "green",
   swatches: 10
}, {
   color: "blue",
   swatches: 5
}];

const result = Object.entries(
   data.reduce((acc, { color, swatches }) => ({ ...acc, [color]: (acc[color] ?? 0) + swatches }), {})
).map(([color, swatches]) => ({ color, swatches }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: elegant - quite literally a one liner! - and unless you're dealing with an array with millions of entries, speed is noth going to be a factor

Comment: can I ask, why use `??` instead of `||` - I understand the difference, just not the reason

Comment: Since it seems like the topic of this question is to achieve it with ES6. So I decided to use `??` instead of `||` to show more possibilities.

Comment: Fair enough - as I said, elegant answer 

Comment: PS: object spread (`{...acc, `), `Object.entries()` and `??` is not ES6, `Object.entries()` is ES8, object spread is ES9 and the Nullish Coalescing Operator is ES11 ;)